# Auto Fill Feature VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to auto fill down from the first cell that I have in cell B1 based on how many rows are in column A.  Any I ideas on how to account for this. Thanks!

```
Set sourceRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A20") 
Set fillRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:B20") 
sourceRange.AutoFill Destination:=fillRange
```

Comment: Do you mean fill across? That code can't work as the destination must include the source? Are you copying a variable number of rows from column A to B?

Comment: You could look at `UsedRange`

Comment: `FillDown` or `FillAcross` are worth investigating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
Dim lr as Long
lr = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Set sourceRange = WorkSheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A" & lr)
Set fillRange = sourceRange.Resize(, sourceRange.Columns.Count + 1)
sourceRange.AutoFill Destination:=fillRange
```

---

**EDIT:**

Note, as it's unclear from your question, if you also wish to detect last column,
then:

```
Dim lc as Long
lc = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

will detect it for you, you can adjust your sourcerange, and set your fillRange to be the rightmost adjacent column

```
Set sourceRange = WorkSheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(1,1), Cells(lr, lc))
Set fillRange = sourceRange.Resize(, sourceRange.Columns.Count + 1)
sourceRange.AutoFill Destination:=fillRange
```

will do the trick!

Comment: I think OP is looking for total columns and not rows. Which is just a variant of your answer

Comment: It's kind of unclear. I thoguht so as well originally, but it kind of defeats the purpose if he directly references next column (B) as the fill range.

Comment: @SJR yeah that's just oversight on my part, as I copied OP's code instead of transcribing it myself. Will edit in a sec

Comment: @Zac edited my answor to accomodate last column being used as well. But I still find it kind of funky in practical use.

Comment: Not sure what OP wants now because now I think they have changed it to look for number of rows.. atleast you've covered both :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a guess as not sure what you are trying to do.

```
Sub x()

Dim SourceRange As Range, fillRange As Range

With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set SourceRange = .Range("A1", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    Set fillRange = .Range("A1").Resize(SourceRange.Rows.Count, 2)
End With

SourceRange.AutoFill Destination:=fillRange

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found to circumvent this issue is as follows

```
Range("B1").Select
Selection.Copy
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range(Selection, "B1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Doesn't quite auto fill but should do the job for you.

Comment: Even better if you can do dispense with the Selects.

Comment: @SJR What do you mean dispense with the selects? I just tried this code and it worked for me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba?rq=1

Comment: Are you meaning to set a range as opposed to using select?

Comment: @BRPOR In general it's best to avoid `.Select`  altogether (causes a lot of unexpected behaviour and so on). The code will work, but it is teaching a bad habit. I really like the question SJR linked to, one of the latter answers pretty nicely explains not only how you should avoid it, but also why you should avoid it